# If else condition is expression or statement in Groovy?

Tags: groovy

Seems like in version 4 groovy turned statements into expressions, but this code still not works, why?

```
def v = if (1 < 2) { true } else { false }
println(v)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are referring to, but if I had to guess it'd be switch expressions?  The short answer is just because `switch` got a make over doesn't mean `if` did too.  Plus we already have a more compact syntax for this with the ternary operator:

```
def v = 1 < 2 ? true : false
println( v )
```

So turning if from a statement into an expression offers little improvement over existing syntax.

Plus you have everything you need to do this on your own with Groovy:

```
def <T> T test( def expr, Closure<T> truthExpression, Closure<T> falseExpression = null ) {
   if( expr ) {
      return truthExpression.call()
   } else {
      return falseExpression.call()
   }
}

def result = test( x < 1, { y + 10 }, { z + 100 } )
```

You could get fancier with it with a class and [method chaining](https://blog.mrhaki.com/2011/05/groovy-goodness-command-chain.html) so you could have a DSL like approach:

```
    def result = test( x < 1 ) then {
       y + 10
    } else {
       z + 100
    }
```

At this point there is little reason to refactor `if` into an expression because you can do pretty much the exact same thing using the Groovy of today (and technically yesterday too).

Comment: ternary operator doesn't support multiline if/else

Comment: Yes it does :-) x < 1 ? getSuccess() : getFailure()

Comment: I can make an even better answer though which I will amend my answer.